# how to do ssr rendering in vuejs2 app that doesn't have any webpack template

Tags: vuejs2

I am new to vuejs and I followed [this link](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/133/How-to-Install-Vue-2---Through-CDN,-NPM-and-the-Vue-CLI) for creating a new project with vue cli. I created the vue cli without using any webpack templates. What the use of creating the project with webpack template? How can I do SSR rendering in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#installation

Example:

```
// Step 1: Create a Vue instance
const Vue = require('vue')
const app = new Vue({
  template: `<div>Hello World</div>`
})

// Step 2: Create a renderer
const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer()

// Step 3: Render the Vue instance to HTML
renderer.renderToString(app, (err, html) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(html)
  // => <div data-server-rendered="true">Hello World</div>
})

// in 2.5.0+, returns a Promise if no callback is passed:
renderer.renderToString(app).then(html => {
  console.log(html)
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```